# Passing data from the second view into the first view controller

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I want to know how do you pass data, like values, from a second view controller into the first view controller. I did a simple segue from the first to the second. I just don't know how to do it backwards.

I have a view on my first controller, and a view on the second one. I want to pass the changes from the second view into the view on the first controller when I click on a custom back button I made. How do I go about doing that?

I know it has something to do with unwind segue, but everything I look up is very unclear and confusing.

Comment: See the "passing data back" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/1271826. Or see unwind segue references in other answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it backwards, you could do it with `delegate` or `blocks` like what @Rob linked in the comments.

You can also do a unwind segue like what you mention. Just like a simple segue, unwind segue could help you pass data from the second view controller to first view controller in `prepareForSegue`.

Example you have a `ViewControllerA` that segue to the `ViewControllerB`. This time you want to setup the unwind segue for `ViewControllerB` to `ViewControllerA`. Before setting up on storyboard, you will need to setup the `@IBAction` in **`ViewControllerA`** the `UIViewController` you want to unwind to not `ViewControllerB`. Something like this:

```
@IBAction func cancelToViewControllerA(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

In storyboard, at the `ViewControllerB` control drag the `button` that will call the unwind segue to the `exit` and select `cancelToViewControllerA`. Then give it a name for the unwind segue. In `ViewControllerB` override `prepareForSegue` like what you did for passing data forward to set the data for the unwind segue.

Comment: in your last sentence you say, " In ViewControllerB override prepareForSegue like what you did for passing data forward to set the data for the unwind segue." can explain that part a little further? how do you override the prepareForSegue routine in order to pass data back similarly to the way it was passed forward?